# Chrome extension - GCM Notification throws error but information is there?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise

My chrome extension keeps throwing an error to this function

```
 function messageReceived(message) {
  // A message is an object with a data property that
  // consists of key-value pairs.

  // Pop up a notification to show the GCM message.
  chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
    title: message.data.name,
    iconUrl: 'assets/img/cat.jpg',
    type: 'basic',
    message: message.data.prompt,
    buttons : [
    { title: "Accept" },
    { title: "Reject" }
    ]
  }, function() {});
}
```

Error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running notifications.create: Some of the required properties are missing: type, iconUrl, title and message.
>       at messageReceived

However, all these are actually present. The error arrives EVERYTIME I add the following function

```
function notificationBtnClicked(notification, ibtn) {
  console.log(notification)
  console.log(ibtn)

  if (ibtn==0) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("name", function(name){
      chrome.storage.local.get("email",function(email){
          //call other users
          var email = email
          var name = name
          $.ajax({
               url: 'some api',
               data:'{email:email, name:name}',
               ajax:true,
               success: function(result)
               {
                 alert(result);
               }
             });
      });
    })

  }else {
    //snooze
  }
}
```

But, I don't understand what's the issue. I checked the chrome.storage by downloading some chrome extension that lets you view it and its there.

Why is the error incorrect? :/

```
chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(messageReceived);
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(notificationBtnClicked);
```

Comment: Hi @Newbie. Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all required notification properties have their value. The '***iconUrl***' you used must be a data URL, a blob URL or URL related to a resource within the extension's .crx file required for  [***'notification.create'***](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create) method. Please be mindful of the Chrome version you are using.

Also, include a callback and check  [***chrome.runtime.lastError***](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError)

```
function callback() {
if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
} else {
// Tab exists
}
}
```